# Анимация CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, collapsing-toolbar-layout

Мне нужно сделать свой бар, фоном которого будет проскроливающаяся картинка, как на прикрепленных скринах.Знаю как сделать такое активити, но никак не могу понять как сделать копию этой анимации[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: это Toolbar + CoordinatorLayout если я правильно понял

Comment: Да, правильно понял)